# Varnish (6.2.1) , Apache Version(Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)) , HA-Proxy version 2.0.13-2

Tags: varnish

Need help in varnish why varnishlog command is not working it does not throws any response.
root@r2m-web-prod:/etc/varnish# cat /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service
[Unit]
Description=Varnish HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/6.1/ man:varnishd

[Service]
Type=simple
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :8888 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/varnishreload
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Below is the complete configuration file of varnish file which is in the directory of /etc/varnish/default.

root@r2m-web-prod:/etc/varnish# cat /etc/default/varnish

## Configuration file for varnish

## /etc/init.d/varnish expects the variables $DAEMON_OPTS, $NFILES and $MEMLOCK

## to be set from this shell script fragment.

## Note: If systemd is installed, this file is obsolete and ignored.  Please see

## /usr/share/doc/varnish/examples/varnish.systemd-drop-in.conf

## Should we start varnishd at boot?  Set to "no" to disable.

START=yes

## Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)

NFILES=131072

## Maximum locked memory size (for ulimit -l)

## Used for locking the shared memory log in memory.  If you increase log size,

## you need to increase this number as well

MEMLOCK=82000

## Default varnish instance name is the local nodename.  Can be overridden with

## the -n switch, to have more instances on a single server.

## You may need to uncomment this variable for alternatives 1 and 3 below.

## INSTANCE=$(uname -n)

## This file contains 4 alternatives, please use only one.

### Alternative 1, Minimal configuration, no VCL

## Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to

## content server on localhost:8080.  Use a 1GB fixed-size cache file.

## This example uses the INSTANCE variable above, which you need to uncomment.

## DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \

## -T localhost:6082 \

## -b localhost:8080 \

## -u varnish -g varnish \

## -S /etc/varnish/secret \

## -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"

### Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL

## Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to

## one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.

DAEMON_OPTS="-a :8888 
-T localhost:6082 
-f /etc/varnish/default.vcl 
-S /etc/varnish/secret 
-s malloc,256m"

### Alternative 3, Advanced configuration

## This example uses the INSTANCE variable above, which you need to uncomment.

## See varnishd(1) for more information.

## # Main configuration file. You probably want to change it :)

## VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl

## # Default address and port to bind to

## # Blank address means all IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces, otherwise specify

## # a host name, an IPv4 dotted quad, or an IPv6 address in brackets.

VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS= 45.12.51.22
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=8888

## # Telnet admin interface listen address and port

## VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1

## VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082

## # Cache file location

## VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE=/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin

## # Cache file size: in bytes, optionally using k / M / G / T suffix,

## # or in percentage of available disk space using the % suffix.

## VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE=1G

## # File containing administration secret

## VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret

## # Backend storage specification

## VARNISH_STORAGE="file,${VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE},${VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE}"

## # Default TTL used when the backend does not specify one

## VARNISH_TTL=120

## # DAEMON_OPTS is used by the init script.  If you add or remove options, make

## # sure you update this section, too.

## DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} \

## -f ${VARNISH_VCL_CONF} \

## -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} \

## -t ${VARNISH_TTL} \

## -S ${VARNISH_SECRET_FILE} \

## -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE}"

### Alternative 4, Do It Yourself

## DAEMON_OPTS=""

Next this is the default configuration file which i extracted from magento hosting.

root@r2m-web-prod:/etc/varnish# cat /etc/varnish/varnish.vcl

## VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 6

vcl 4.0;

import std;

## The minimal Varnish version is 6.0

## For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
.host = "45.12.51.22";
.port = "8080";
.first_byte_timeout = 600s;
.probe = {
.url = "/pub/health_check.php";
.timeout = 2s;
.interval = 5s;
.window = 10;
.threshold = 5;
}
}

acl purge {
"45.12.51.22";
}

sub vcl_recv {
if (req.method == "PURGE") {
if (client.ip !~ purge) {
return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
}
# To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
# has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
# capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
}
if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
}
if (req.http.X-Pool) {
ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
}
return (synth(200, "Purged"));
}

```
if (req.method != "GET" &&
    req.method != "HEAD" &&
    req.method != "PUT" &&
    req.method != "POST" &&
    req.method != "TRACE" &&
    req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
    req.method != "DELETE") {
      /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
      return (pipe);
}

# We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
    return (pass);
}

# Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
    return (pass);
}

# Bypass health check requests
if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
    return (pass);
}

# Set initial grace period usage status
set req.http.grace = "none";

# normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

# collect all cookies
std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

# Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
        # No point in compressing these
        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    } else {
        # unknown algorithm
        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
}

# Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
}

# Static files caching
if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
    # Static files should not be cached by default
    return (pass);

    # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
    unset req.http.Https;
    unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

return (hash);
```

}

sub vcl_hash {
if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
}

```
# For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
if (req.http.host) {
    hash_data(req.http.host);
} else {
    hash_data(server.ip);
}

# To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
}


if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
    call process_graphql_headers;
}
```

}

sub process_graphql_headers {
if (req.http.Store) {
hash_data(req.http.Store);
}
if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
}
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

```
set beresp.grace = 3d;

if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
    set beresp.do_esi = true;
}

if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
    set beresp.do_gzip = true;
}

if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
    set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
}

# cache only successfully responses and 404s
if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
    set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
} elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
    return (deliver);
}

# validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
```

## If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass

if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
(!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
# Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
set beresp.ttl = 120s;
set beresp.uncacheable = true;
}

```
return (deliver);
```

}

sub vcl_deliver {
if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
} else {
set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
}
} else {
unset resp.http.Age;
}

```
Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
    set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
    set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
    set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
}

#unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
#unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
#unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
#unset resp.http.Server;
#unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
#unset resp.http.Via;
#unset resp.http.Link;
```

}

sub vcl_hit {
if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
# Hit within TTL period
return (deliver);
}
if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
# Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
return (deliver);
} else {
# Hit after TTL and grace expiration
return (restart);
}
} else {
# server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
return (deliver);
}
}

I am Novice to varnish configuration after stucking from many weeks now it has been running but there are many command are not working.

if anyone can help in this task i would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible to restructure your question and clean up the markup? It's hard to find the right information in all that unstructured output.

Comment: Hi I mean that when i use this command